# Checar se um mesmo valor está em algum dos dois campos

Tags: mysql

Num sistema de *login*, quero que o usuário digite o "usuário" ou o "email" que está contido na DB.

Isso funciona perfeitamente:

```
DBRead('usuarios', "WHERE usuario = '$user' OR email ='$user' AND senha = '$password'");
```

Porém, odeio repetir código. Existe uma forma mais lógica de realizar essa verificação?

Algo como:

```
WHERE usuario or email = '$user'
```

Comment: Isso não é exatamente repetir código, você stá fazendo duas coisas diferentes. Eu sei que algumas pessoas tem obsessão por escrever o mínimo de código possível, eu mesmo já fui assim, isso não leva a nada, na verdade chega prejudicar bastante. Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101. Frequentemente esse tipo de código leva a problema no código. De fato esse código é **bem** inseguro, isso deveria ser sua preocupação. Até tem como fazer o que deseja.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pela dica! Não é que eu queira escrever menos código, apenas gosto de trabalhar usando uma lógica (acho que me possibilita aprender mais sobre tudo) xD Abraço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanto para pesquisar se um campo tem vários valores quanto pesquisar se um valor se encontra em vários diferentes pode usar o `IN`. Veja dois exemplos:

```
SELECT ... WHERE id IN (1,5,6,9); -- retorna linhas onde o ID é um, cinco, seis ou nove
```

e, para pesquisar um valor em mais de um campo:

```
SELECT ... WHERE "xis" IN (principal, reserva, outros); -- retorna linhas em que ao menos
                                                        -- um dos três campos listados
                                                        -- seja a string "xis"
```

Ficando assim no seu caso:

```
WHERE '$user' IN ( usuario, email ) AND senha = '$password'
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/205ff/1)**.

O `IN` começa a ficar vantajoso em vários parâmetros, por exemplo em `IN ( usuario, email, inscricao, cpf )` se um dia precisar disso em alguma aplicação. O ganho em velocidade/processamento é mínimo (economiza basicamente a transmissão e alocação de valores repetidos), mas a facilidade de manutenção e legibilidade aumenta um bocado.

<sub>Notar que você está com uma porta aberta para SQL Injection se não sanitizar os parâmetros, e armazenar senhas diretamente no DB não se faz em situações reais.</sub>

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou de boa.
Sobre  SQL Injection: Minha função tem um Escape.

Answer (score 2):

Esse é o jeito que se faz. Não tem atalho.

Mas sugiro delimitar entre parênteses para evitar inconsistência:

```
DBRead('usuarios', "WHERE (usuario = '$user' OR email ='$user') AND senha = '$password'");
```

Obviamente, desconsiderando o uso de [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/views.html) ou funções customizadas.