# MySQL comparar um numero com string retorna verdadeiro se a string começar pelo número

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, select

Tenho a seguinte tabela na base de dados:

idUser - Username - Group

1 - John - 5GR

2 - Doe - 1GR

E a seguinte query:

```
    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `idUser` = '$name' OR `Group = '$name'
```

$name é a variável que contem o valor que utilizador introduz.

Quando o utilizador introduz 1, apenas o utilizador com o idUser=1 é apresentado.
Isto está correcto.

Quando o utilizador introduz 2, apenas o utilizador com o idUser=2 é apresentado.
Isto também está correcto.

O problema é quando o utilizador introduz '1GR'.

O correcto seria apresentar apenas o utilizador com o Group = 1GR, neste caso o utilizador Doe.

No entanto o utilizador John é também apresentado porque o seu idUser = 1 e a string introduzida pelo utilizador contém 1.
O problema é da comparação com o idUser, eu verifiquei se retirar essa comparação da query ele apresenta correctamente (no entanto o utilizador ja nao podera procurar por id user e isto é essencial).

Existe alguma maneira de arranjar isto?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que está havendo um cast implícito da *string* buscada, pois você está comparando um número com uma *string*. Você pode forçar a interpretação do `idUser` como *string* desta forma:

```
CAST(`idUser` AS CHAR)
```

Note que também há um errinho na *query*, falta um `` ` `` no `Group`.

Aplicando os ajustes ao seu caso:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(`idUser` AS CHAR) = '$name' OR `Group` = '$name'
```

Não se esqueça de usar o `mysqli_real_escape_string()` do lado do PHP para evitar injeção de SQL caso o usuário digite o caractere `'` (ou outros caracteres especiais) na busca.

### Simplificando a *query*

Como busca o mesmo valor em mais de uma coluna, pode escrever desta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '$name' IN ( `Group`, CAST(`idUser` AS CHAR) )
```

Mais detalhes aqui:

> [Checar se um mesmo valor está em algum dos dois campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163715/70)